# How to find a particular dictionary in a list of dictionaries using key comparisons

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of tasks that contain `task1` and `task2`. I don't want to append `task3` if `record_id` of `task3` matches the existing tasks. So in short if `record_id` of 2 items in the list `tasks` have same values, the task is considered same.

```
task1 = {
        'record_id': '1,2,3',
        'location': 'l1',
        'instruction_parameters': {
            'NAME': 'project_name1'
        },
        'marked_points': 'marked_points1',
        'marked_polygons': 'marked_polygons1',
    }
task2 = {
        'record_id': '8,7,3',
        'location': 'l2',
        'instruction_parameters': {
            'NAME': 'project_name2'
        },
        'marked_points': 'marked_points2',
        'marked_polygons': 'marked_polygons2',
    }

tasks = [task1, task2]

task3 = {
        'record_id': '3,1,2',
        'location': '',
        'instruction_parameters': {
            'NAME': 'project_name3'
        },
        'marked_points': 'marked_points3',
        'marked_polygons': 'marked_polygons3',
    }

task3_record_ids = task3['record_id'].split(',')
```

I tried the following approach but the first gave me `StopIteration` error and the second did not return anything.

```
previous_dup_task_dict = next(item for item in tasks if set(item['record_id'].split(',')) == set(task3_record_ids))
```

Second approach :

```
previous_dup_task_dict = filter(lambda task: set(task['record_id'].split(',')) == set(record_ids), tasks)
```

Note that the order of `record_id`s doesn't matter so in this case `task3` should match `task1` as their `record_id`s have same values even though in different order, which is acceptable.

Comment: `I don't want to append task 3 if one of the keys of task3 matches the existing tasks.` Are two tasks can be marked as identical if `record_id` contains same value? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @arsho sorry please see my edits. Only if record_id is same, then 2 tasks are considered identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should compare all tasks in list with task3 this way:

```
task1 = {
    'record_id': '1,2,3',
    'location': 'l1',
    'instruction_parameters': {
        'NAME': 'project_name1'
    },
    'marked_points': 'marked_points1',
    'marked_polygons': 'marked_polygons1',
}
task2 = {
    'record_id': '8,7,3',
    'location': 'l2',
    'instruction_parameters': {
        'NAME': 'project_name2'
    },
    'marked_points': 'marked_points2',
    'marked_polygons': 'marked_polygons2',
}

tasks = [task1, task2]

task3 = {
    'record_id': '3,1,2',
    'location': '',
    'instruction_parameters': {
        'NAME': 'project_name3'
    },
    'marked_points': 'marked_points3',
    'marked_polygons': 'marked_polygons3',
}

match = False
for task in tasks: 
    if set(task3["record_id"].split(",")) == set(task["record_id"].split(",")): #set for ignoring order of list items
        match = True

if not match:
    tasks.append(task3)

print(tasks)
```

you should use set to compare two list without considering index of list items.

Answer (score 0):

If the record_id values are always integers you can sort them after converting into integers. Then you can compare easily. If you want me to elaborate please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
task1 = ...
task2 = ...
task3 = ...
tasks = [task1, task2]
match_found = False
for task in tasks:
    if sorted(task1['record_id'].split(',')) == sorted(task3['record_id'].split(',')):
        match_found = True
    else: 
        continue

if match_found == False:
    tasks.append(task3)
```

First assign a variable for checking if any item with same `record_id` key is present in the list `tasks`. Now, loop through the `tasks` list and split each item's `record_id` by `,` and sort them and compare them with that of `tasks3`. If they match, assign that variable to `True`. Now if the variable is `True` then append `task3` into `tasks` list.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a class as a wrapper. That class can inherit `list`.

```
import json


task1 = {
        'record_id': '1,2,3',
        'location': 'l1',
        'instruction_parameters': {
            'NAME': 'project_name1'
        },
        'marked_points': 'marked_points1',
        'marked_polygons': 'marked_polygons1',
}

task2 = {
    'record_id': '8,7,3',
    'location': 'l2',
    'instruction_parameters': {
        'NAME': 'project_name2'
    },
    'marked_points': 'marked_points2',
    'marked_polygons': 'marked_polygons2',
}

task3 = {
    'record_id': '3,1,2',
    'location': '',
    'instruction_parameters': {
        'NAME': 'project_name3'
    },
    'marked_points': 'marked_points3',
    'marked_polygons': 'marked_polygons3',
}


class Tasks(list):
    def get_identifier(self, s):
        s = s.replace(" ","")
        return sorted(list(map(int, s.split(","))))

    def compare_tasks(self, first_task, second_task):
        if self.get_identifier(first_task['record_id']) == self.get_identifier(second_task['record_id']):
            return True
        return False

    def append(self, new_task):
        task_exist = False
        for task in self:
            if self.compare_tasks(task, new_task):
                task_exist = True
                #raise ValueError('Task already in list: {}'.format(new_task))
        if task_exist == False:
            super().append(new_task)

tasks = Tasks()
tasks.append(task1)
tasks.append(task2)
tasks.append(task3)
print(json.dumps(tasks, indent = 4))
```

**Output:**

```
[
    {
        "location": "l1",
        "marked_points": "marked_points1",
        "instruction_parameters": {
            "NAME": "project_name1"
        },
        "record_id": "1,2,3",
        "marked_polygons": "marked_polygons1"
    },
    {
        "location": "l2",
        "marked_points": "marked_points2",
        "instruction_parameters": {
            "NAME": "project_name2"
        },
        "record_id": "8,7,3",
        "marked_polygons": "marked_polygons2"
    }
]
```

You can raise `ValueError` for adding duplicate task in `tasks`.

To raise `ValueError`, uncomment the following comment:

`#raise ValueError('Task already in list: {}'.format(new_task))`

**Clarifications:**

- `Tasks` inherits `list`.
- Each task has an unique identifier: sorted list of `record_id` key.
- Two tasks are identical if they have same unique identifier.
- `json.dumps` is used to show the list with proper indentation.